# Cell by Cell writing is very slow, but I'm facing a situation in range writing

Tags: c#, excel, file-io

I'm have a very large array, the size of whose depends on an external device, it could either be **65536** or it could be double that **131072** and its data type is **ushort**.

I have to write this entire data into a 65536 Rows * 1 Column **.xlsx** file. I used to write cell by cell but it takes like 4 minutes to complete.

So I thought of using range approach(As given [here](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Write-data-to-an-Excel-worksheet-with-C-fast.aspx)), my partial code is as follows:

```
{
    \\ VoltageFluctuations is of ushort type with 65536 values

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

    // Voltage Fluctuations
    xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    xlWorkSheet1.Name = "Voltage Fluctuations";

    xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, 1] = ("Minutes");
    xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, 2] = ("Voltage");


    var startCell = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2];
    var endCell   = new object();
    endCell = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Cells[65536, 2];
    var writeRange = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range(startCell, endCell);

    writeRange.set_Value(Type.Missing, VoltageFluctuations); 

    // As soon as the above line is executed my program crashes

    // Finally saving this as a .xlsx file type
}
```

The exception I get is:

[image]

Comment: I thought Excel could handle max 65535 rows - is that the problem?

Comment: @Roger But if I write cell-by-cell I'm able to write all the data, the entire 65536 rows + First Row = 65537 rows.

Comment: You're right of course, I'm remembering back to Excel 2003!

Comment: Does the TargetInvocationException thrown have an InnerException? If yes, which, and what Message does it have?

Comment: @Martin in the output window I see these messages:A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: If possible, consider using .NET 4. This makes using COM more fun, e.g. you can omit Type.Missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this problem using [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124):

For UI:

```
  private static Worksheet GetWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument document, string worksheetName = "Sheet1")
    {
        var sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook
            .Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == worksheetName);
        var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart
            .GetPartById(sheets.First().Id);

        return worksheetPart.Worksheet;
    }

    private static string GetColumnName(int columnIndex)
    {
        var dividend = columnIndex;
        var columnName = String.Empty;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            var modifier = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modifier).AsString() + columnName;
            dividend = (dividend - modifier) / 26;
        }

        return columnName;
    }

    private static Cell CreateTextCell(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, object cellValue)
    {
        var cell = new Cell();
        var inlineString = new InlineString();
        var txt = new Text();

        cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
        cell.CellReference = GetColumnName(columnIndex) + rowIndex;
        txt.Text = cellValue.AsString();

        inlineString.AppendChild(txt);
        cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

        return cell;
    }

    private static Row CreateContentRow(int rowIndex, object[] cellValues)
    {
        var row = new Row
        {
            RowIndex = (UInt32)rowIndex
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < cellValues.Length; i++)
        {
            var dataCell = CreateTextCell(i + 1, rowIndex, cellValues[i]);
            row.AppendChild(dataCell);
        }

        return row;
    }
```

Spreadsheet set data:

```
            var sourcePath = "Report_Template.xlsx";
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            var processSettings = new MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings
            (
            MarkupCompatibilityProcessMode.ProcessAllParts,
            FileFormatVersions.Office2007
            );
        var openSettings = new OpenSettings()
        {
            MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings = processSettings,
            AutoSave = true
        };

        using (var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(memoryStream, true, openSettings))
        {

            var worksheet = GetWorksheet(spreadSheet);
            var worksheetPart = worksheet.WorksheetPart;
            const int lastRowIndex = 1;
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var lastRow = sheetData.Elements<Row>().LastOrDefault(l => l.RowIndex == lastRowIndex);
            var reportItems=null;//Get your reoirting data...    

            if (lastRow != null)
            {
                foreach (var newRow in (from reportItem in reportItems
                                        let newRowIndex = lastRow.RowIndex + 1
                                        select CreateContentRow((int)newRowIndex, new object[] 
                    {
                        newRowIndex-lastRow.RowIndex,
                        reportItem.Column1,
                        reportItem.Column2
                {
                    sheetData.InsertAfter(newRow, lastRow);
                }

                worksheet.Save();
            }

        }
```

After & Before methods yet, of referenced row and cell for Insert and Appended data...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare VoltageFluctuations this way:

```
object[,] VoltageFluctuations = new object[65536, 1];
```

(Consider using something like `const int size = 65536`.)

Admittedly, this is not very intuitive, at least not for me. However, arrays of type ushort didn't work at all, and arrays with only one dimension didn't give the expected result, but wrote the first value into all cells.